# Do I need to free memory after call to WriteConsoleW?

Tags: c, windows, console, char, widechar

I am writing a function which prints a formatted string in a Windows console. It takes a simple C string which is a single byte string, converts it into a wide string for the Windows O.S., sends it to the console and frees both buffers. The buffer of a single-byte string is freed normally, but when I free the wide string, the program crashes.

When I free the allocated memory right after the call to `WriteConsoleW`, the application crashes.

Why does it crash ?

Do I need to free that `ws` buffer, supplied to the `WriteConsoleW` function, or does it free it internally and automagically ?

Here is my function:

```c
void console_print(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;

            va_start(args, fmt);
    char *buf = smprintf(fmt, args);
            va_end(args);

    if (buf == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    PDWORD cChars = NULL;
    HANDLE std_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    LPWSTR ws = CHARtoWCHAR(buf, CP_ACP);
    WriteConsoleW(std_out, ws, wcslen(ws), cChars, NULL);

    free(ws); // This line crashes the program.
    free(buf);
}
```

The second buffer for a wide string, the `ws`, is allocated inside the `CHARtoWCHAR` function:

```c
LPWSTR CHARtoWCHAR(LPSTR str, UINT codePage) {
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, str, len, NULL, 0);
    LPWSTR wstr = (LPWSTR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(WCHAR) * size_needed);
    MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, str, len, wstr, size_needed);
    return wstr;
}
```

The `smprintf` function creates a C formatted string.

```c
// Creates a buffer and fills it with a string formatted with the specified
// format and arguments. Caller must free the buffer after usage.
char *smprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;

    // 1. Measure the required size of buffer.
            va_start(args, fmt);
    int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
            va_end(args);

    // 2. Create the buffer.
    char *buf = malloc(++len);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // 3. Fill the buffer.
            va_start(args, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buf, len, fmt, args);
            va_end(args);

    return buf; // Do not forget to use: free(x).
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use `free` instead of `LocalFree` when you want to free a memory block alllocated by `LocalAlloc`? And what is `smprintf`?

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the question. Free memory allocated via `malloc` with `free` and free memory allocated via `LocalAlloc` with `LocalFree` etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jabberwocky.
I forgot to use the `LocalFree`.

```c
LocalFree(ws);
free(buf);
```